# `numpy.piecewise` discards imaginary part of function. Why, and how to workaround?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a piecewise complex function defined

```
import numpy as np

def foo(x):
    return np.piecewise(x, [x>0], [np.exp(1j*x)])
```

When I try to evaluate it, it raises a Warning.

```
print(foo(9.99))
```

Out:

```
-0.8444696962887724
C:\Users\pedro\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\function_base.py:1151: ComplexWarning: Casting complex values to real discards the imaginary part
  y[condlist[k]] = item
```

This is due to the numpy `piecewise`, which is discarding the imaginary part of `np.exp(1j*x)`... Why is that happening? By running the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.12.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L1219-L1347) the Warning is raised in the following lines:

```
if not isinstance(item, collections.Callable):
    y[condlist[k]] = item
else:
    vals = x[condlist[k]]
    if vals.size > 0:
        y[condlist[k]] = item(vals)
```

I could not understand it. Also, how can I work around this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the **first array is an int/float** array (or a scalar in this case). So `piecewise` will first construct an array based on that value, and then call the function from it. But at that point, the type of the array is already fixed.

You can however solve the problem, by making it a complex number as well, by adding `0j` to it:

```
def foo(x):
    return np.piecewise(x+0j, [x>0], [np.exp(1j*x)])
    #                    ^ turn x into a complex number
```

Or use the `complex(..)` constructor:

```
def foo(x):
    return np.piecewise(complex(x), [x>0], [np.exp(1j*x)])
    #                   ^ turn x into a complex number
```

This generates:

```
>>> foo(9.99)
array((-0.8444696962887724-0.5356033346142913j))
```

In case `x` is already an array, you can use [**`x.astype(dtype=np.complex)`**](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.astype.html) to turn it into a complex array.